# Why one column is always has zero when we use two COUNT requests?

Tags: sql, counting

I'm trying to get table with 3 columns: 1- year, 2- quantity of foreign cars, 3- quantity of Russian cars (grouped by year). Values from the table having columns: 1- year, 2- type, 3- id application.
Result is always the same - one of the column with quantity is 0 or both of columns has the same values, another words, it is wrong . Where is the mistake?
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JSuz.jpg) [source table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMVAc.jpg)
I was trying different ways:

```
SELECT autotable.year as Year, 
       count(CASE WHEN autotable.Type='Foreign' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as Quantity_Foreign_Cars, 
       count(CASE WHEN autotable.Type= 'Russia' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as Quantity_Russian_Cars 
FROM banktest.autotable 
group by autotable.Year;

SELECT autotable.year as Year, 
       sum(IF (autotable.Type='Foreign',1,0)) as Foreign_Cars,
       sum(IF (autotable.Type ='Russia',1,0)) as Russian_Cars 
FROM banktest.autotable 
group by autotable.Year;

SELECT autotable.year as Year, 
       (SELECT count(autotable.Type) 
        FROM banktest.autotable 
        where autotable.Type='Foreign') as Foreign_Cars,
       (SELECT count(autotable.Type) 
        FROM banktest.autotable 
        having autotable.Type='Russia') as Russian_Cars 
FROM banktest.autotable 
group by autotable.Year;
```

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read, and to write.

Comment: Please tag your specific database, *format* your query to be readable without scrolling and add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The second and third query are invalid standard SQL

Comment: @Stu Table (FROM):  Year / Type /id Application .    Table (have to get): Year(grouped by year)/Count foreign cars(from type)/Count russian cars(from type)

Comment: result, for example  :  2007 / 5  / 2  ; 2008 / 1  /6  Now it is always .. / 0 /..  ;  ../ 0 /..   ;   .../ 0 /..

Answer (score 0):

So as far as i understand, you are having a table with 2 columns. Year and Type, right?
You need to group by both of your columns and use the count method.

If you are using a oracle database this should do the trick:

```
select count(*), trunc(year,'Y'), type 
from autotable
group by 
trunc(year,'Y'), type;
```

Comment: The same result..(

Comment: I have table: columns : 1- year, 2- type, 3- id application. I need to get 1- year (it should be grouped by year) 2- Count foreign cars(from type)3- Count Russian cars (from type)

Comment: Could you please tell us what the outcome should look like exactly?

Comment: result should be in table look like:  1 column- year (it should be grouped by year) 2 column- Count foreign cars(from type) 3 column- Count Russian cars (from type).  For example: 2007/4/1 , 2008/1/2

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
select count(case when type = 'Foreign' then 1 end) as foreign, count(case 
when type = 'Russia' then 1 end) as russian, trunc(year,'Y')
from autotable
group by 
trunc(year,'Y')
```